# How many PE (Parsing Engine) can be configured in a Teradata Box

Tags: teradata

Lets say, for a system with 8 nodes and 368 AMPS, what is the number of PE that be configured? And How many sessions can each PE can handle (The default is 120)

Answer (score 0):

Max 10 PEs per node are permissible, but better is to add 2 PE per node (it will give you optimal performance).

1 PE supports 128 sessions where 8 are reserved for internal use. SO 128-8 = 120 sessions per PE is usable by users.